# Why does code execution in SSH only work after session is started

Tags: ssh, cross-compiling

I'm trying to set up a cross-compiling environment for my raspberry pi and I wanted to use SSH to see the output directly on my PC. I'm using Notepad++ and I wrote some batch script to compile upload and execute C++ code. It works fine for most code, but when I try to use a specific library (OpenCV) it tells me there was an error loading libopencv_core.so. The strange part is that the code runs perfectly when I open a SSH session on cmd and then execute it. After some testing, I came to the conclusion that the code only fails if I write this

```
ssh pi@raspberrypi ./executable_file
```

but works perfectly file if I do it like this

```
ssh pi@raspberrypi
```

and once the terminal opens then execute the file. What is the problem here?

Comment: The main difference is with the former you get a non-interactive shell which does not read ~/.bashrc on startup, which may make a difference for things like library path environment variables.

Comment: do you know a way I can get around this?